# On Summation of series.

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I want to prove that the sum

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \{\frac{\zeta(m)X^{m}\ln(mX)}{m!}\}$

[Where ln(mX) is the usual natural logarithm of mX and X is any possitive number and zeta(m) is Riemann's Function.]

Converges to a definite sum .

Please give me a simple way in which this theorem to be proved .

Thanks..

Comment: When $m=1$ your summand does not exist.

Comment: If you replace $m=1$ with $m=2$, then the sum converges for all fixed $X$ because $\zeta(m)\le\zeta(2)$